# Machine learning, removing noisy class (not individual instances)

Tags: machine-learning

My question is regarding a dataset which after cross-validation (CV), helps me identify the class which is causing the greatest amount of error. For instance, consider the following CV data:

```
               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.194     0.015      0.315     0.194     0.24       0.786    A
                 0.369     0.024      0.571     0.369     0.449      0.844    B
                 0.096     0.015      0.167     0.096     0.122      0.688    C
                 0.478     0.015      0.558     0.478     0.515      0.858    D
                 0.648     0.01       0.768     0.648     0.703      0.904    E
                 0.481     0.019      0.82      0.481     0.606      0.928    F
                 0.358     0.012      0.646     0.358     0.461      0.862    G
                 1         0.001      0.973     1         0.986      1        H
                 0.635     0.005      0.825     0.635     0.717      0.959    I
                 0.176     0.003      0.667     0.176     0.278      0.923    J
                 0.999     0.346      0.717     0.999     0.835      0.984    K
Weighted Avg.    0.704     0.169      0.692     0.704     0.671      0.931
```

From the example, it is apparent that class K weighs down the combined accuracy (note the FP rate which is important in my context). Now my question is, would it be wise to ignore class K altogether from the training set? Or would it be better to consider test instance classification only for the more accurate classes (say, in this example, any class but K).

My argument against ignoring the whole class such as K, is that one may force a test instance actually belonging to class K, to fit some other class, which seems illogical.

Any inputs?

Thanks

Comment: I want to note here that this does not simply pertain to noise reduction through individual instance modification (which I have done thorough research on).

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the actual problem you tackle, e.g.: do the classes reflect an objective ground-truth (e.g. trying to classify a text to the writer who wrote it) or are the classes arbitrary (e.g. classifying "round" vs. "non round" objects)? What are the relative weights of type-I vs. type-II errors, and how important is recall (coverage)?

However, a practical method I can suggest is hierarchical classification.

Specifically: using the CV confusion matrix, find pairs (or groups) of classes which are not neatly separated; group them together as a single class; and then train a secondary classifier to separate only the classes belonging to the group. This might lead to a more accurate classification, especially if you find out that in order to classify a specific group, another set of features/classification algorithms would be better.

For example, say your confusion matrix is:

```
       class/classified as
               |A |B |C |D 
              A|10|2 |1 |3
              B|0 |15|0 |1
              C|0 |0 |21|16
              D|0 |0 |9 |11
```

clearly, there is a large amount of confusion between C and D. you could retrain the same classifier with just 3 classes, A, B and E (C and D combined), then try separating only C and D with a new classifier whenever E is found.

Comment: This is exactly what I did with another of my system that I developed. Based on your input I revisited my confusion matrix and it looks like all the other classes are contributing false positives to class K. What I did also observe (and should've really paid attention at the beginning) was that the number of training instances for class K are way more than any other class. So now I am going to randomly sample class K instances to reflect an even distribution and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding class K having way more samples than other classes - this is exactly where you could use @Brabster's answer, i.e. use all samples, but with error costs which would balance the tendency to classify into it. Alternatively, depending on your learning algorithm, you can also assign lower weight to class K instances (e.g. using the "j" parameter of SVMLight)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to try and find a way of assigning a cost to false positives that reduces this risk for the class K.

Comment: Brabster, that would be a good approach in the case where I am bent upon improving the classification only for class K. Here, however, I need the system as a whole to perform accurately. By associating cost with certain false positives, it would be more like a game of poking a water balloon with no real system improvement.